# docker run -p not exposing port if i include --net=<macvlan> and --ip=<ip>

Tags: docker, containers, arm64

On my rpi4 i am running docker container with simple FastAPI app and running it with uvicorn, i set docker network to map the container traffic only to the ethernet port using macvlan. Now when i run my container using below command, i dont see the port being exposed, although i see the container running fine (using `docker logs -f <container>`.

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
ADD ubuntu-focal-oci-arm64-root.tar.gz /

ENV TZ=America/Toronto
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN mkdir shared_volume

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-pip firefox firefox-geckodriver -y --no-install-recommends
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn","updater:app", "--workers", "4", "--reload"]
```

and i build it normally with:

```
sudo docker build -t me/app:1.0 .
```

then i run it:

```
sudo docker run \
-p 18000:8000 \
-itd \
-e CONTAINER_NAME='app_1' \
--net=docker_macvlan_1 \
--ip=192.168.3.111 \
--mount source=shared_volume,target=/app/shared_volume \
--name app_1\
<image_id>
```

If i call it that way above, i dont see the ports expose to my host.
If i remove --net and --ip, i see the port exposed.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `macvlan` network, all container ports are exposed on the IP that you give to the container. In other words, when you use `macvlan` it is the same as ***forward all connections to this IP to the container***, where as when you use port forwarding it is like ***forward all connections to this host port to that container port***.

Thus, just try connecting to the IP you gave the container and the port your application is listening on. You don't need port forwarding with `macvlan`, port forwarding is for `bridge` (the default and aka NAT) network driver, which is used when you do not specify `--net=docker_macvlan_1` in `docker run` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it may seem to have worked, however when i try to curl it on my host's terminal it is now giving me `Connection refused` error.
edit: removed the command, but basically its just curl

Comment: @Ritsard well, if a connection refused, then at least it is. Does the app listen on any IP (0.0.0.0)? Does the same curl work from inside the container? Which port have you used to get the error? 8000?

Comment: yes, uvicorn host is set to 0.0.0.0
i have yet to try curl within the container, but afaik the logs shows uvicorn server properly.
yes, default port is 8000.
Do you think this has something to do with firewall at this point?